# Problema com Tabs e Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Estou com um problema aqui.

Tenho esse código

Tela Inicial: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class Inicial extends AppCompatActivity {


private ImageButton button,button2;


        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicial);

            button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent it = new Intent(Inicial.this,MainActivity1.class);
                    startActivity(it);
                }
            });

            button2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);




    }}
```

MainActivity:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Praça XV - Araribóia"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Araribóia - Praça XV"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tempo de viagem"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}}
```

PageAdapter

```
class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;
public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            TabFragment1 tab1 = new TabFragment1();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            TabFragment2 tab2 = new TabFragment2();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            TabFragment3 tab3 = new TabFragment3();
            return tab3;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Todas com seus respectivos xml.

Agora com as fotos, quero clicar em outra estação, por exemplos PRACA XV - CHARITAS e abrir uma tela igual a SEGUNDA foto mas, claro, com horários diferentes e etc.

Agora eu quero adicionar outro botão na TELA INICIAL para que quando o usuário aperte ele abra uma outra tela idêntica a essa MAIN ACTIVITY só que com outras informações. Como se fosse uma MAIN ACTIVITY2.

Eu copiei e colei trocando os id's e tá dando crash direto.

O que pode ser?

CÓDIGO DO ERRO QUANDO CRASH

06-08 09:06:45.398 7073-7073/com.aplicativos.facilita.teste E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.aplicativos.facilita.teste, PID: 7073
                                                                              android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.aplicativos.facilita.teste/com.aplicativos.facilita.teste.MainActivity1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1628)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1424)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3424)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:50)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:79)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3385)
                                                                                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:859)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3627)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3595)
                                                                                  at com.aplicativos.facilita.teste.Inicial$2.onClick(Inicial.java:44)
                                                                                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
                                                                                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Pode colocar os erros que deram?

Comment: Não dá erro.. na hora que clico no outro botão que era pra abrir outra tela com as abas o app fecha.

Comment: @MarioAndréFranco nao erro de compilacao, erro quando o app da crash

Comment: @leofontes é isso msm. Queria colocar a foto das telas pra explicar melhor mas nao estou conseguindo

Comment: Vc falou que tá dando crash, então é um erro. Tem que mostrar oq diz quando esse erro acontece. Só olhar no android monitor.

Comment: @Marceloawq coloquei agora

Comment: @Marceloawq Graças a você descobri o que era pelo android monitor. A activity não estava no Manifest! Obrigado

Comment: Opa @MarioAndréFranco então tá certo! Tente não criar atividades copiando e colando o java e xml, sempre use o menu `new` clicando com o botão direito no pacote.